# Primary Key of the DB as PHP header info

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have created a registration form which is in `application.php` and when submitted it is processed and the contents are stored using `submit.php` and I want to redirect to `thanks.php` with a parameter called message with value equal to the primay key of the recently inserted row.. For example it should return my 100th applicant to the page,

`www.mydomain.com/thanks.php?message=100`

where 100 is the Primary key (AI).

In other words I want to print the primary key of the table as a refernce id for the users.. I tried

`header("location: thanks.php?message=".$id);` and

`header("location: thanks.php?message=".$_POST['id']);`

Both dont work for me.

Kindly help me guys!

EDIT:

```
require("admin/sources/connection.php");

$id = mysql_insert_id();

// Other variables are declared here

$sql = "my_INSERT_query_goes_here";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result) {

    header("location: thanks.php?message=".$id);
}
```

This is my `submit.php` code

Comment: Let's see the rest of `submit.php`

Comment: What do you mean by: "it didn't work?"

Comment: @webbiedave added as edit :) @TimWolla everytime it goes to `www.mydomain.com/thanks.php?message=0` and not the required id.. But contents are updated in DB correctly!

Comment: For the record, `require` is a construct, not a function, no need for parans.

Comment: `$id = mysql_insert_id();` should be executed after the query is run ... otherwise there is no insert id ...

Comment: @MikePurcell Thanks for pointing out. I am a php beginner and will soon learn them sorry!

Comment: @dleifah I run that before inserting and I use that $id value in my INSERT query.. I see no difference.. can you please enlighten me? and anyways its not working even if I place after the query

Comment: @vivek1794 ... I've added an answer with some theories on why it isn't working and some clarification on `insert_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple issues ... it looks like you're mixing `mysql_` methods with `mysqli` and you have the execution in the wrong order.

If your database table is auto-increment, you don't need to pass an ID in the query. By calling `$id = mysql_insert_id();` and using the id in the query, you're passing in 0 as the id which uses the next auto-increment id.

Getting the `insert_id` after `$conn->query($sql);` will return to you the insert id used.

Echo some variables to see what values you're getting for `mysql_insert_id();` before and after.

However, if you're doing a `$conn->query()`, then you're not using the standard `mysql_` functions.

Try this:

```
require "admin/sources/connection.php";

// Other variables are declared here

$sql = "my_INSERT_query_goes_here";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result) {
    $id = $conn->insert_id;
    header("location: thanks.php?message=".$id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Wrong execution order - simple fix

You are first assigning $id, and then running the query.

Twist them around to make it work.

Not using auto-increment?

I see in the query in your comment, that you manually pass the id you want to enter. Did you realize that `mysql_insert_id()` will not return the sql column that you did call "id", but the column that you set an auto-increment on? That is a single row in your table that automaticly gets an incrementing number without the need to manually enter it.

Comment: I tried this one `$sql = "INSERT into register Values ('$id', *other variables*)"; $result = $conn->query($sql); $id = mysql_insert_id(); if($result) { header("location: thanks.php?message=".$id); }`  But its not working! still message is passed with arg 0